# visual diagram editor that converts diagrams to text

Tags: uml, wysiwyg, diagram, plantuml

I want to be able to create and edit UML-style Diagrams with a graphical editor, and then store a textual representation of that diagram (something that can be part of a version control system).

What good tools are there to perform this kind of task?

I know that the opposite is possible (one can create a diagram using plantUML script and than convert it to a diagram image).

Comment: your question is not clear, what must be textual, the representation of the diagram/picture (this is the case of svg pictures) or the memorization of the "project" allowing to generate the diagram, or may be both ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

1) Many UML tools that support export of XMI (an XML-based model interchange format). The XMI can be version controlled.

2) Tools like [Sparx Systems](https://www.sparxsystems.com/) EA allow you to use a version control system (CVS, Subversion, git etc) to change-manage model content as a feature of the app.

3) You can use a tool that uses a text-based file to store its models. [Continuity](https://www.continuity.kiwi.nz) does this (XML-based files) as do others.

Answer (score -2):

Better to edit yourself in a text editor (like notepad++, textpad etc) with block mode selection (Alt+Selection). You can draw one block and copy-paste (or Ctrl+Drag) to create pictures.

Or google for "ascii art converter"